# How to kill or pause a process without killing its InputStream?

Tags: android, process

I want to start a `getevent` process inside the application by using:

```
Process get_event_process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getevent");
```

and get its output by using a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader
      (new InputStreamReader(get_event_process.getInputStream()));

String line = "";
log = new StringBuilder();
while((line = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null) {
     log.append(line);
}
```

The main problem is that the `getevent` process will never end unless it's killed. And if I kill the process I will lose my `InputStream` with itself.

Is there a way to interrupt, pause the process, and get the produced input until that time?

Or is there a way to save the input of a never ending process like `sh -c getevent` even if I kill the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, I have found the solution with using ProcessBuilder instead of Process.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder().command("getevent").redirectErrorStream(true);
Process get_event_process = builder.start();
```

Unfortunately it will stuck on while loop and give the output like this:

```
/dev/input/event5  Permission denied.
/dev/input/event4  Permission denied.
/dev/input/event3  Permission denied.
/dev/input/event2  Permission denied.
/dev/input/event1  Permission denied.
/dev/input/event0  Permission denied.
```

So with a rooted phone you can get the output by using:

```
chmod 666 /dev/input/*
```

Cheers.